# is it better to store platform configuration in database or a file?

Tags: database, file, configuration

currently we are developing an app in which we use database table to store platform settings, like maximum file size, maximum users number, support email, etc.

it means that each time we add a platform setting we have to add a column to this table.

in my previous projects i am used to store such information in file.

what is better/faster approach?

ps, i am almost sure someone already had such question, but i can't seem to find it

Comment: If you need to add a new column if a new type of whatever you are storing appears, your schema is probably not normalized.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It really depends on your application.

Storing the settings in the database has several advantages:

1. Security - users can easily alter settings in the file or overwrite the contents.
2. For Distribution - the same settings can be updated and loaded onto any machines on the network.

Disadvantages:

1. Relies on database connection
2. Overhead when reading from database

Storing in file advantages:

1. Fast and easy to read and modify.

Disadvantages:

1. Security issue as mentioned above.
2. May need encryption on sensitive data.
3. Versioning is difficult, since you have to create separate files for different versions.

it means that each time we add a platform setting we have to add a column to this table
- depending on what database you are using, but you can store the whole settings as XML (SQL server allows this) in the table, so you do not need to alter the table schema everytime adding a settings; all you need to do is to modify  the XML, adding elements to it or removing from it.

but in the end, you have to decide yourself, 
there's no better or worse for everyone.

Comment: -1. I think the signal to noise ratio is pretty low here. Many points just don't make sense. Like "overhead when reading from a database". What overhead? A few ms? Read the config once. And "relies on database connection". So does the rest of the app. Then you're saying store an XML "file" in the database? What advantage is there? And file versioning. File versioning is easy, any version control system does it. Database versioning is a more difficult problem.

Comment: Sry, Let me clarify a little:

1. The app doesn't have to rely on any database connection, its just an option as mentioned in the question.

2. XML allows hierarchy information to be encapsulated, rather than just flat key, value pair table.

3. Versioning - I guess you are right, easy or difficult really depends on how you set it up too, so I would agree on you.

4. Overhead - Read the config once, yes, I suppose, but you might also want to do updates and reload sometimes to update or get updated config; like I said, it depends on the whole architecture.

Comment: I find this answer very misleading.  Configuration often does NOT belong in DB.  As a dev / architect having spent 18 years programming in various corporate environnemnts and large scale apps, I totally  do not agree with this answer.

Versioning configuration ( to track changes) is a must for any application doing "important stuff".  See my answer below.

Comment: @JéQueue There's a few solutions to this that allow runtime change. (But you certainly don't want to query the database every time a config is used). You can store in cache with an invalidation period. 15 minutes seem fine. Saying that it takes 15 minutes to update a configuration at any given time is really fine, and I've seen this be common in many places. The other, more fun one, is to have an open socket on the box that allows you to initiate a connection and tell it to invalidate its configuration cache so that it will repull the next time a config is requested.

Answer (score 69):

We store config settings in a key/value type table, something like:

```
CREATE TABLE Configuration.GlobalSettings
(
    SectionName VARCHAR(50),
    SettingName VARCHAR(50),
    SettingValue VARCHAR(1000),
    SettingType TINYINT
);
```

The `SectionName` & `SettingName` are the primary key, we just split them up to make it easier to query what is in a section, and to allow the loading of individual sections into handlers rather than loading the whole lot at once. The `SettingValue` is a string, and then the `SettingType` is a discriminator that tells us how the setting value should be interpreted (e.g. 1 = string, 2 = bool, 3 = decimal, etc.).

This means you don't have to change the table structure for new settings, just add a new one in the deployment script or wherever it is you set these things up.

We find it a better way do do config than a file because it means you can easily programmatically change config values through an admin interface when needed, which can enforce logic around what can go into each setting. You can't do that so easily with a file (though, of course, it is possible).

Comment: Hello, i know this is a very old post, but why is it not easy to change config values when saving the config into a file? Via Properties/Preferences it is actually very easy to do so or am i missing something?

Comment: Properties files are great if you have one or two servers - when you're deploying on tens of them then it's less fun...

Comment: Isn't NoSQL Key/Value stores a better way to store such settings nowadays?

Comment: Yep. The world has changed a lot in 5 years.

Comment: Postgres with HSTORE or JSONB may do NoSQL better than NoSQL for your app.

Comment: I'd suggest `SettingSection` for the first column, so we have identical prefixes that are much easier to “remember” (i.e., forget).

Answer (score 41):

I can tell you as I manage a particularly large application at numerous sites that keeping configs in local files is a complete pain.  Often times the configs are read and cached and not able to be changed during run time others have scale-out systems where configs need to be repeatedly changed and bounced.

My life would be 10% easier during system landscape implementation if the designers would just keep system properties at the DB.

Comment: +1 for not drastically overstating the percentage of easierness this approach delivers.

Answer (score 15):

Why a new column every time? Why not just 2 columns: NAME and VALUE.

What we do is set defaults in a file, then override those defaults in the database when needed, per deployment.

Also, in terms of speed, we cache the configuration (with the ability to trigger a reload). Makes no sense to re-read the configuration every time you need a property from it. So in terms of speed, it doesn't really matter. You do it once.

Comment: Last post is a ini-like configuration with section implement.

Comment: I know this is really old, but I found this really helpful. I was asking myself a question...how can I make my application's setting easily accessible to the administrators through the GUI AND not write a table which contains only one row that may constantly change? This is the perfect answer, and also helps avoid forcing `NULL` column values for unused settings.

Answer (score 9):

To be fair, the answer is not so cut and clear.

The answers above do not seem to take into account applications that need to be deployed in different environnements ie: dev , qa, staging, prod.

They also do not take into account the importance of versioning configuration, ie knowing who changed what, where and when.

All modern frameworks provide a way of fetching proper configuration for specific environments, usually via environment variable.

Each environnment has its own config, consider the way symfony lays out its configuration files:

```
your-project/
├─ app/
│  ├─ ...
│  └─ config/
│     ├─ config.yml
│     ├─ config_dev.yml
│     ├─ config_prod.yml
│     ├─ config_test.yml
│     ├─ parameters.yml
│     ├─ parameters.yml.dist
│     ├─ routing.yml
│     ├─ routing_dev.yml
│     └─ security.yml
├─ ...
```

For these reasons, I most certainly prefer configuration in file.

My 2 cents.

Comment: I don't see anything in this answer that addressed the advantages or disadvantages of using a database. *Or* the pros/cons of a file. Really it seems only to touch upon the *feasibility* of using a file, and then declares that because it is feasible, it is preferred. Am I missing something?

Comment: @JimCullen - Maybe I was not clear enough, for configuration management and the ability to have different configurations for different environments ie local, dev, qa, stage, prod  many favor file based configuration,  this also allows for the versioning of configuration, knowing who changed what / where.  Accountability.

Configuration in database does not scale well at all in corporate environments, and accountability is lost.

My 2 cents

Comment: What if we don't really give importance to whether the app will be deployed on different environments ? What if the configurations is like about how much options can a user fill on a form ?

Comment: @MehdiFracso - You are correct that dynamic configuration is normally stored in database. Though even in this context, there is a workaround that gives more flexibility.  In the Laravel application I currently maintain, default settings are in yml files ( same for every environment) and can be overidden via ui forms, whose values are saved in DB and overide default settings.  This allows to set variables in config files, even set them via ENV variables when deploying if needed, and have them overidden if needed by end-user through a UI.

Comment: I wish I could +1 this answer another hundred times. With build and deploy automation, there is even less reason to keep settings in a (custom) database when they can easily just be managed by those respective servers. And those servers, in the end, often enough use configuration files. I don't want to have to configure Octo to load settings from a table someone invented when it's perfectly capable of managing that on its own.

Answer (score 2):

I think like everyone said, depends on your application environment and requirements. But if I had to pick a general rule, I'd say BOTH.
First, you create a database table to store all your configurations. This is good for two reasons:
1) Versioning - allows you to easily keep track of previous configurations.
2) Management - You can create an interface that your users can access to change settings.

Secondly, you create a file that after you saved and published the site to production, it will also save all those settings into a file that will be easily accessed. In fact, if you are programming in PHP for the web, that file should be a php file with array data (key-value pairs) that need no further manipulation. By this I mean, no need to convert your yaml, or json into array if that is the final output you need to have.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, it depends. The questions that need to be asked are: How often does the setting need to be changed? If it needs to be changed does it imply there are larger changes being made, or is the functionality to accept that different value already in place? And most importantly...What is your deployment process? If you have an automated deployment process and the predicted frequency of value changing is weekly or longer I would typically use a settings file.

Why? versioning and environment promotion. The exact thing that makes it convenient to toggle this here and that there at a whim can make it almost impossible to say "My dev environment is stable and working as expected lets promote the changes to the next env." Why, because unknown to you the enableSuperDuperFeatureEveryoneExpects was toggled to false by unknown acceptance tester last Friday. Now  there are ways around this and in small applications with 5 configs and 1 developer its a non-issue, but if you are working on a enterprise application with 8 teams with 100s of config tables over 40 schemas you have a nightmare that never ends. This can be solved more or less with a config schema...but I personally would try and keep as few configs as possible in a db unless your application is small...and to define "small" I would say as soon as there are multiple teams on an application your application is no longer small.

Another concern with db config is protection against invalid entries being made on the fly. If your application has a configuration, lets say defaultLandingPageAfterAuth and the only accepted values are home and dashboard and someone accidently puts homw in prod on a Friday afternoon...what happens? Now you can use db enums...which I recommend...but do you?